# Add formatter function to json data received from REST API on bootstrapvue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am receiving the following json data from REST API into my bootstrap-vue vue.js v2.6 app.

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "key": "name",
            "label": "name",
            "sortable": true
        },  
        {
            "key": "item1",
            "label": "item1",
            "sortable": true
        },
        {
            "key": "item2",
            "label": "item2",
            "sortable": true            
        },
        {
            "key": "item3",
            "label": "item3",
            "sortable": true
        }
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Field name 1",
            "item1": -0.05,
            "item2": -0.06,
            "item3": -0.07
        },
        {
            "name": "Field name 2", 
            "item1": -0.01,
            "item2": -0.02,
            "item3": -0.03
        },
        {
            "name": "Field name 3", 
            "item1": -0.05,
            "item2": -0.06,
            "item3": -0.07
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to add a formatter function to this json data. It will look like this;

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "key": "name",
            "label": "name",
            "sortable": true
        },  
        {
            "key": "item1",
            "label": "item1",
            "sortable": true
        },
        {
            "key": "item2",
            "label": "item2",
            "sortable": true,
            "formatter": "value => { return (value + '%')}"
        },
        {
            "key": "item3",
            "label": "item3",
            "sortable": true
        }
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Field name 1",
            "item1": -0.05,
            "item2": -0.06,
            "item3": -0.07
        },
        {
            "name": "Field name 2", 
            "item1": -0.01,
            "item2": -0.02,
            "item3": -0.03
        },
        {
            "name": "Field name 3", 
            "item1": -0.05,
            "item2": -0.06,
            "item3": -0.07
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the Vue.js code I wrote to do this;

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="pt-2 pb-3">Bootstrap Table</h1>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields" primary-key></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

async function axiosGetRequest(url) {
  const axios = require("axios");  
  let res = await axios.get(url);

  return res.data;
}

export default {  
  data: data_init,
  mounted: function() {
      let url = "http://localhost:8080/temp.json";     
      
      axiosGetRequest(url).then((res) => {
        this.fields = amend_fields(res.fields);
        this.items = res.items;
        console.log(this.fields);
      });        
  },
};

function data_init() {  
  
  let init_data = {};
  init_data.fields = {};
  init_data.items = {};

  return init_data;
}

// amend fields object
function amend_fields(fields) {   
  let new_fields = {}; 
  new_fields = fields;
  new_fields[2]["formatter"] = "value => {return (value + '%')}"; 

  return new_fields;
}

</script>
```

Unfortunately, the code does not seem to work. There is no error message. If it works, I will see a percentage sign added as a suffix to item2 column in the table created by BootstrapVue. However, I cannot see this. This is what I saw.

[image]

Anyone knows what is wrong with my code?

I am using vue.js v2.6 and BootstrapVue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the [`formatter` field](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#formatter-callback) is a string, the string must be the **name of a function**, not a string value of the function itself.

In your case, just remove the quotes from the `formatter` value:

```js
// "formatter": "value => { return (value + '%')}" ❌ don't use a string
"formatter": value => { return (value + '%')} ✅
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-bootstrap-vue-table-formatter?file=src/components/MyTable.vue)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to add a percentage sign added as a suffix to item2 column in the table created by BootstrapVue, then this can be achieved in another way.

Define `fields` in javascript code. Read only the data in `items` from the REST API json data.

In fact, it is unusual for an API to define how the `fields` in your table should look. How would an API designer know that? This information should be defined in your own code. It is the wrong architecture to extract `fields` from an API.

Here's how the modified code will look like.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="pt-2 pb-3">Bootstrap Table</h1>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields" primary-key></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

async function axiosGetRequest(url) {
  const axios = require("axios");  
  let res = await axios.get(url);

  return res.data;
}

export default {  
  data: data_init,
  mounted: function() {
      let url = "http://localhost:8080/temp.json";   
      
      axiosGetRequest(url).then((res) => {
        //this.fields = amend_fields(res.fields); //Don't read fields data from REST API. Define yourself.
        this.items = res.items;
        console.log(this.fields);
      });        
  },
};

function data_init() {  
  
  let init_data = {};
  init_data.fields = [
        {
            "key": "name",
            "label": "name",
            "sortable": true
        },  
        {
            "key": "item1",
            "label": "item1",
            "sortable": true
        },
        {
            "key": "item2",
            "label": "item2",
            "sortable": true,
            "formatter": "value => { return (value + '%')}"
        },
        {
            "key": "item3",
            "label": "item3",
            "sortable": true
        }
    ];
  init_data.items = {};

  return init_data;
}

</script>
```